# Why does my Geth full node stop working when it is out of sync?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3.py, synchronization, full-node, lighthouse

I am using geth (with Lighthouse as consensus client) to work on the Göerli testnet

Whenever i am trying to use the localhost RPC (127.0.0.1) or the IPC in my dApp, if my node is a few blocks behind ( like 100 blocks or so ) , it does not return a proper response

for instance,

`Web3.eth.blockNumber`

returns 0 !

so, is this a limitation of geth ? that we can't use it unless it is fully synced ?

or is there a way around this?

P.S : I am using Ubuntu 20.04